# How does Pub-sub model works internally under JMS or Redis/Kafka?

Tags: java, jms, publish-subscribe

I understand that there is a publisher which will start publishing events to a topic/channel and all the subscribers registered to the topic/channels will start receiving the events.

I am looking to understand the mechanism which is used internally? Is it websockets/TCP connection?

Is subscriber like a background thread running and waiting on TCP port?

-Thanks